# Authentication in .net core with various AuthenticateResults

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am new to .net core. We are trying to add auth to a project.

My HandleAuthenticateAsync function of Authentication handler looks like this.

```
        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            string token = Gettoken(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request);
            if(token == null)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
            }
            
            
            if(Validatetoken(token) == false)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("invalid token");
            }

            var tokenIdentity = new TokenIdentity(token);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(tokenIdentity, null);
            var authTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "schema");
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(authTicket);
        }
```

I want to throw client side error only when the token is invalid(on AuthenticateResult.Fail)
and want to proceed with processing the request in other cases(on AuthenticateResult.NoResult and AuthenticateResult.Success)

How can I achieve this requirement? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use authorization filters or action filter to handle this requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-filters